# How can I conditionally include specific code in my Android app based on certain conditions?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, onesignal, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on an experimental Android app builder that operates in the cloud. I want to provide users with the option to enable or disable OneSignal for push notifications within their generated apps. Depending on their choice, I need to include or remove OneSignal-related code.

Here's what I've attempted so far: I've created a Gradle task to check if the `one_signal_app` variable is not empty, and then include the necessary code. My project is using the Kotlin DSL.

Here's the task code I'm using:

```
tasks.register("includeOneSignalInDemand") {
    doLast {
        val oneSignalAppId = appConfig.getProperty(AppConfig.APP_ONESIGNAL_ID)

        if (oneSignalAppId != null && oneSignalAppId != "") {
            val code = """
                OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE)
                OneSignal.initWithContext(this)
                OneSignal.setAppId(BuildConfig.ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID)
                OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications()
            """.trimIndent()

            val appKtFilePath = "${projectDir}/src/main/java/package_here/App.kt"
            val existingCode = file(appKtFilePath).readText()

            val insertionPoint = existingCode.indexOf("super.onCreate()") + "super.onCreate()".length
            val updatedCode = StringBuilder(existingCode).insert(insertionPoint, code).toString()

            file(appKtFilePath).writeText(updatedCode)

            println(updatedCode)
        }
    }
}

tasks.named("preBuild").configure {
    dependsOn("includeOneSignalInDemand")
}
```

However, I'm encountering two main problems with this approach:

First Problem: The code is correctly added to `App.kt`, but it's missing the necessary import statement for OneSignal. I've attempted to add the import in the same way I include the code, but it doesn't feel like a clean solution.

Second Problem: As my OneSignal configuration grows, adding code this way becomes messy and challenging to maintain.

Is there a better way to include this code, perhaps using a file template, and ensure that the necessary imports are also handled automatically?

Comment: You are searching for `flavors` https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants